# Undefined variable $addtailer

Tags: php, laravel, undefined

List item

**Controller**

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\TailerInfo;
use App\Models\AddTailer;
    
class ClothnaapController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        // forgin key data code
        $tailerinfo = TailerInfo::where('add_tailer_id', 'id')->get();
        $addtailer = Addtailer::get();

        return view('frontend.clothesnaap', compact('tailerinfo', 'addtailer'));
    }  
}
```

**View**

```
<div class="p-2">
    <label class="leading-7 text-sm text-gray-600" for="tailer name">
        Tailer Name
    </label>
    <select name="tailername" id="">
        @foreach ($addtailer as $addtailers)
            <option value="{{$addtailers->id}}">{{$addtailers->name}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Problem is in your where query. 'id' should be a declared variable or a number and Addtailer::all() should be correct. Get doesn't work in this situation

Comment: Use  Addtailer::all() instead of get , according to documentation of laravel https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#retrieving-models

Comment: Have you tried to `dd($addtailer)` in the controller? Looks to me like that is not the controller function you are calling. in this code `$addtailer` is defined.  @AqibJaved `Addtailer::get()` should work just fine, and the variable would still be defined. 
Side note: i would call the collection $addtailers and the single model in the foreach $addtailer.

Comment: @GertB. `dd($addtailer)` no point doing that since the error already mentioned `Undefined variable` like you have mentioned that blade file, it should be that the blade file is not the one the view method is calling from the controller or OP is looking at the wrong Controller method.

Answer (score 0):

According to your Question there is `case-sensitivity` problem, check your `Addtailer` class/Model name:

```
use App\Models\AddTailer;
```

When you initialize class you are writing `T` capital but when you are using it in `index` function, using `t` small.

```
$addtailer = Addtailer::get();
```

**It Must** be same as you initialize it.

```
$addtailer = AddTailer::get();
```